# How to update sum of multiple tables in another table

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables: mtsr1a, engr1a and mainscores as shown below.

This table is a course with matric number as Column2 and total performance as Column7

mtsr1a

```
Column2     Column7
15/001      8       
15/002      6       
15/003      7       
15/004      3       
15/005      7
```

This table is another course with matric number as Column2 and total performance as Column7

engr1a

```
Column2     Column7
15/001      9       
15/002      6       
15/003      4       
15/004      8       
15/005      1
```

This is the sql code i used to get the sum of both tables

It works well on mysql but reverts when  browser is refreshed

```
select Column2,sum(Column7) total
from
(
    select Column2,Column7
    from mtsr1a
    union all
    select Column2,Column7
    from engr1a
) t
group by Column2
```

Using the code i got the sum better

```
Column2     total
15/001      17      
15/002      12      
15/003      11      
15/004      11      
15/005      8
```

which is very correct but i want code that i will use and update the next table which have the overall_scores column with the result i got above.

I am expecting something like:

mainscores

```
Column2     overall_scores
15/001      17      
15/002      12      
15/003      11      
15/004      11      
15/005      8
```

- I have tried severally on my own but i know it will be a solution to other newbies like me in the future. I need this in order to make my ranking which i already have a code here but if that can be included, it will be an added advantage for me to learn.
- Another is how to use that sql code in php for it to update the database when admin clicks a button.
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to insert both the column value in 3rd table then use `insert into .. select from` like

```
insert into mainscores
select Column2,
sum(Column7) total 
from (select Column2,
             Column7 
             from mtsr1a 
         union all 
             select Column2,
                    Column7 from engr1a ) t 
group by Column2
```

(OR)

If you want to `UPDATE` a specific column then use a update join like

```
UPDATE mainscores a 
    JOIN (
    select Column2,
    sum(Column7) total 
    from (select Column2,
                 Column7 
                 from mtsr1a 
             union all 
                 select Column2,
                        Column7 from engr1a ) t 
    group by Column2 ) xx
ON a.Column2 = xx.Column2 
SET a.overall_scores = xx.total;
```

Comment: Please i don't understand this because it shows  #1054 - Unknown column 'a.total' in 'field list'

Comment: My bad, it should be `a.overall_scores`. See edit in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [Main_Table]  set [Main_Table]= sumVal.total from Main_Table
     JOIN (
     select [column2],
     sum([column7]) total 
        from (select [column2],
                 [column7] 
                 from [mtsr1a] 
             union all 
                 select [column2], 
                        [column7] from [engr1a] ) val 
    group by [column2])sumVal
ON Main_Table.[column2] = sumVal.[column2]
```